# C# Base64 String to JPEG Image

Tags: c#, image, base64, jpeg, encode

I am trying to convert a Base64String to an image which needs to be saved locally.

At the moment, my code is able to save the image but when I open the saved image, it says "Invalid Image".

[image]

Code:

```
try
{
    using (var imageFile = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    {
        imageFile.Write(resizeImage.Content);
        imageFile.Close();
    }
}
```

The `Content` is a `string` object which contains the Base64 String.

Comment: You can use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get a byte array. Then from there you load that into a `MemoryStream` or use the array as input to an `Image` or you can write out to a `File`.
but providing the code you have already will help immensely.

Comment: There's multiple things wrong that I can see. Firstly, you're not writing a binary file.. You also don't appear to be decoding the base64 anywhere..

Comment: Ahah thank you. I'll shall give that a try.

Comment: @ByteBlast - Sorry I thought I had pasted the code in but I hadn't and published the question.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

So with the code you have provided.

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(resizeImage.Content);
using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    imageFile.Write(bytes ,0, bytes.Length);
    imageFile.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. That worked wonders. I now understand that I had to convert/decode the string.

Comment: Thanks, this was working for me to convert the contentBytes string of a attachment json reply from the Microsoft graph. Now I can save my atttachments to real files.

Answer (score 107):

First, convert the base 64 string to an `Image`, then use the `Image.Save` method.

To convert from base 64 string to `Image`:

```
 public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
    // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
 }
```

To convert from `Image` to base 64 string:

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to base 64 string
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

Finally, you can easily to call `Image.Save(filePath);` to save the image.

Comment: you are more than welcome, please mark the reply as answer if it solved your problem, you too :)

Comment: +1 for the reverse solution. I was looking for that. :-)

Comment: Isn't ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length) redundant here? Seems like MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes) will create MemoryStream and initialize it with imageBytes, so Write() is not needed.

Comment: thank you for the hint, that code when I answered was without testing, I will add note in the answer.

Comment: @HadiHassan Your memorystream should be wrapped in a using

Comment: Any idea on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751449/save-taskstring-type-to-string-giving-catastrophic-failure?noredirect=1#comment49559004_30751449

Comment: iam  getting  a  error  like  ..system.windows.Controls.Image  does  not   contain a  definition  for  "FromStream"..... please  help..

Comment: @Kartiikeya Image belongs to "System.Drawing" and not system.windows.controls

Comment: Why not closing `MemoryStream` in `Base64ToImage`?

Comment: @Andy according to Microsoft, the using statement automatically closes the stream and calls dispose on the object when the code that is using it has completed. you can see this reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

Comment: @HadiHassan in `ImageToBase64` I totally agree. But in `Base64ToImage` I don't see a `using` or a `Close()`.

Comment: @Andy i edited the answer to include the using statement, thank you for the tip

Comment: using visual studio community 2015, windows 10, Image appear to not be a class of System.Drawing?

Answer (score 8):

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
   // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Front :

```
  <Image Name="camImage"/>
```

Back:

```
 public async void Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            // read stream
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
            var image = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();

            // decode image
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(image);
            image.Seek(0);

            // create bitmap
            var output = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelHeight, (int)decoder.PixelWidth);
            await output.SetSourceAsync(image);

            camImage.Source = output;
        }
```

Comment: How about convert Image to Byte?