# Converting binary image data received from a webservice to a byte[]

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, httpclient, binary-data

in a Windows store app project i have this method

```
private async void getUSerImage()
    {
        try
        {

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = Constants.baseAddress })
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", App.Current.Resources["token"] as string);

                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("user/image"))
                {
                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseData);

                    StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("userImage.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, bytes);
                    var stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

im trying to convert the binary data received to bytes and save it as a file
this is what the responseData contains something like this:
[image]

the image gets created but its corrupt , i can't open it i assume this

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseData);
```

does't work

the webservice documentation says that "The body contains the binary image data"
is there any better way to convert the binary data im receiving to bytes and save it to a file?

**EDIT:**

i ended up doing this and it worked

```
Stream imageStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[imageStream.Length];

                    imageStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);


                    StorageFile sampleFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("userImage.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, bytes);
                    var stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: oh, ill edit my post :) sorry

Comment: refer it may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in case anyone else stumbles upon it, I believe the first three lines of code in Ric's solution can be replaced with byte[] bytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the data into a stream first rather than reading it as a string:

```
Stream imageStream= await response.Content.GetStreamAsync(theURI);
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream);
image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

// Get the stream 

var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

if you want to show the image instead of saving could use

```
$('img')[0].src = 'Home/getUSerImage' // what ever image url
```