# base64 to image filename

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have code that crops a image when a user clicks on a button:

```
$('#crop').click(function () {
    var imageDataBase64 = $('#image-cropper').cropit('export');
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = imageDataBase64;
    console.log(image);
});
```

The picture should be uploaded as a coverpicture for the user.

How should I save this picture? Should I store the base64-code in the database? Or Is there any way to transform the base64 to an image and then store It on disk and then store only the reference to the image in the database?

EDIT:

I found the following solution: [C# Base64 String to JPEG Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image)

Comment: What you should store in DB is completely up to you. For the second part there are hundreds of "convert data image to file" questions... You may want to research existing solutions first...

Comment: _"Or Is there any way to transform the base64 to an image"_  What is `imageDataBase64` ? The `base64` string could be `data URI` representation of image file

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: But what Is a good solution for this? I have done some researched, and I can't really find anything that says that I can transform a base64-string to a jpeg-file and then store It on disk programmatically. Any ideas?

Comment: guest271314: What? ImageDataBase64 Is the base64 string.

Comment: Never mind. I found a solution.

Comment: I have no idea what/where are you searching - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+save+data+image+base64+file gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400173/converting-a-base-64-string-to-an-image-and-saving-it

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions. Looks like flagging as duplicate or deleting is right solution (if your solution is more than link to existing SO question posting self-answer would be appropriate)