# Can change img src value to Image?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image

How can i get image from img src attribute.When i get like this

```
 var imagevalue=$('#image').attr('src')
```

It return encrypt string like:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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........
```

How can i change this encrypt string to Image in server side or client side?

Comment: How will you use the image on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, if you're using C# you can do the following:

```
    public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
    // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
    test = base64String.Split(',')[1];byte[] imageBytes = 
       Convert.FromBase64String(test);
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
 }
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image) for additional info.

Comment: Thx @Christian, When i try to change base64string to byte array it say"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character ". But i try with  string test = base64String.Split(',')[1];byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(test); It work.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

create an Image object and put the base64 as its src

```
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,/9j/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoM.....';
  document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help.

using System;

using System.Drawing;

using System.IO;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static string data = @"data:image/png;base64,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";

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var base64Data = Regex.Match(data, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
    var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(binData))
    {
        var pictureBox = new PictureBox {
            Image = new Bitmap(stream),
        };

        var form = new Form { AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink };
        form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

}

Reference-https://gist.github.com/vbfox/484643