# Download image without prefix of url C#

Tags: c#, image, download

I want to download an image has link like this:

> data:image/png;base64,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

but when I use:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
```

it throw to exception: "uri prefix is not recognized"

Comment: There is nothing to download. Take the string after `base64,` (in your case `iVBOR...`. Decode the base64 to binary and save the byte[] to a file. Done.

Comment: It is the fisrt time I see base64, thank you so much, my problem has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO image link to download. It is base64 representation of the image, so the image is encoded in the string and embedded into the document.
You can get the base64 representation of the string and convert it to image as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827081/c-sharp-base64-string-to-jpeg-image). Pasting the code for quick reference.

```
 public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
    // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is the fisrt time I see base64, my problem has been resolved