# How to send message through sql with an image

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, html-email, email-attachments

In my SQL, I already created profile & account.

I also know how to send the message though code :

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='yourprofilename',
@recipients='test@Example.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
```

** Above is an example

However, I was wondering how can I insert an image into the message.

Comment: you could embed a base64 string representation of the image into a html message... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863685/sending-an-image-as-attachment-using-sp-send-dbmail/59864406#59864406

Comment: Sry, i have tried this, it didnt work.